# Unable to access Jupyter Notebook instance on GCP Deep Learning VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I have set up the Cloud SDK for running a Deep Learning VM on Google Cloud Platform but when I try to access the Jupyter Notebook instance i get this error from the terminal.

[image]

From my terminal I ran the following command to access the SSH instance:

```
 gcloud beta compute --project "driverdrowsiness" ssh --zone "asia-east1-a" "tensorflow-1-vm" -- -L 8005:127.0.0.1:8888
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there, could you please tell us where is your Jupyter instance running? Is it on an AI Notebooks (another GCP product)? If not, where is it? Also, could you please add to your question the settings of both of your GCE environments (the deep learning VM and the AI Notebook - in case it is in this product)?  For that last part I only would like to see settings about connectivity (serial ports enabled, accepting specific traffic, etc.). That would help us to help you better :)

Comment: Hey I figured out the problem I needed to open it from the AI Notebooks works fine now thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to open JupyterLab from the AI Notebooks